# R data frame unsplit: invalid factor level, NAs generated

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an array which contains a data frame at each entry (data frame has column 'hospital' and 'state'):

```
> groups
$AK
   hospital state
AK       NA    AK

$AL
                         hospital state
AL D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL

$AR
                            hospital state
AR ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER    AR
```

When I call the `unsplit` method I can't have a correctly unified data frame:

```
> unsplit(groups, dimnames(groups) ) 
                            hospital state
AK                              <NA>    AK
AL    D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL  <NA>
AR ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER  <NA>
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "AL") :
  : invalid factor level, NAs generated 
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "AR") :
  : invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

It's driving me NUTS for hours. How can I have my data frame correctly reunited?

Thanks

Comment: I would do `do.call(rbind,groups)`

Comment: Does `unsplit(lapply(groups, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, as.character); x}), names(groups))` do it? I think you just have factors with differing levels in each data.frame. But @MaratTalipov 's comment is probably more straight-forward.

Comment: `rbindlist(groups)` from `data.table` is a much faster alternative to `do.call(rbind,groups)`